# How can I aggregate a column's value based on the min() and max() values of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data-frame, `df`, that is population with 1000+ rows of data. Here is what it would look like:

```
     date        mkt       bid       ask
0    01/07/22    LWAPO     0.6451    0.6460
1    01/07/22    HUYNE     0.6452    0.6458
2    01/07/22    VERAS     0.6447    0.6457
3    02/07/22    HUYNE     0.6432    0.6435
4    03/07/22    LWAPO     0.6440    0.6442
5    03/07/22    VERAS     0.6441    0.6444
6    03/07/22    PLAIN     0.6440    0.6445
7    03/07/22    ALCOT     0.6445    0.6449
8    04/07/22    HUYNE     0.6431    0.6444
9    04/07/22    LWAPO     0.6439    0.6441
...
```

My goal is to aggregate this date by the date, and perform some analysis using the mean bid/ask prices by each of the market makers, that is `'mkt'` column, and finally visualise this data using plotly.

However, I am wanting the `'mkt'` column (or it can be a new column if easier) to populate the names of the two market makers with the best bid price (max) and the best ask price (min), as a concatenated string.

As such, it would be something that looks like below:

```
     date        mkt
0    01/07/22    HUYNE, VERAS
1    02/07/22    HUYNE, HUYNE
2    03/07/22    ALCOT, VERAS
3    04/07/22    LWAPO, LWAPO
...
```

With the other two columns just being simple averages for the day. I can achieve this through the following code:

`new_df = df.groupby('date').mean()`

But unsure how to properly apply `df.loc[BOOLEAN`]` to alter my data-frame and achieve my desired result. I have a vague idea in mind on how I can do it, but I feel like there is a simple solution that I am missing. I have also tried the following to no avail:

```
for date in df['date'].unique():
    test = df.loc[df['date']==date]['bid'].max()
```

Apologies for the convoluted nature of my question, but I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get name of `bid` max and name of `ask` min

```
df1 = (df.groupby('date')
       .agg({'bid': lambda x: df.loc[x.idxmax(), 'mkt'],
             'ask': lambda x: df.loc[x.idxmin(), 'mkt']})
       .reset_index())
```

`df1`:

```
    date        bid     ask
0   01/07/22    HUYNE   VERAS
1   02/07/22    HUYNE   HUYNE
2   03/07/22    ALCOT   LWAPO
3   04/07/22    LWAPO   LWAPO
```

make result to `mkt` column

```
df1['mkt'] = df1.pop('bid') + ', ' + df1.pop('ask')
```

`df1`:

```
    date        mkt
0   01/07/22    HUYNE, VERAS
1   02/07/22    HUYNE, HUYNE
2   03/07/22    ALCOT, LWAPO
3   04/07/22    LWAPO, LWAPO
```

if don want make `df1` and useless columns, use following code:

```
(df.groupby('date')
 .agg({'bid': lambda x: df.loc[x.idxmax(), 'mkt'],
       'ask': lambda x: df.loc[x.idxmin(), 'mkt']})
 .reset_index()
 .assign(mkt=lambda x: x.pop('bid') + ', ' + x.pop('ask')))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but I do have a follow-up question if you don't mind: if I just needed the 'mkt' column rather than the whole data-frame, how can I alter the code to do so and save myself some memory?

Answer (score 0):

Groupby dates and get the best bid and ask mkt.

```
bids = df[['date', 'mkt', 'bid']]
asks = df[['date', 'mkt', 'ask']]
best_bid_mkt = bids.groupby('date').max().mkt
best_ask_mkt = asks.groupby('date').min().mkt
```

Concatenate the `best_bid_mkt` and `best_ask_mkt` inside DataFrame.

```
best_mkt = pd.DataFrame(best_bid_mkt + ', ' + best_ask_mkt)

date        mkt
07-01-2022  VERAS, HUYNE
07-02-2022  HUYNE, HUYNE
07-03-2022  VERAS, ALCOT
07-04-2022  LWAPO, HUYNE
```

If you wanted to isolate the `mkt` column, then...

```
best_mkt.reset_index(drop='inplace')

    mkt
0   VERAS, HUYNE
1   HUYNE, HUYNE
2   VERAS, ALCOT
3   LWAPO, HUYNE
```

Also could isolate `mkt` column to a list.

```
list(best_mkt.mkt)

['VERAS, HUYNE', 'HUYNE, HUYNE', 'VERAS, ALCOT', 'LWAPO, HUYNE']
```

Or an array.

```
best_mkt.mkt.values

array(['VERAS, HUYNE', 'HUYNE, HUYNE', 'VERAS, ALCOT', 'LWAPO, HUYNE'],
      dtype=object)
```